# Fixed width font for sending mails - notmuch + gmailieer + emacs - How?

Tags: fonts, notmuch

I have recently set-up my personal mail(gmail) for use through emacs, notmuch and gmailieer. For sending mails, I am relying on the inbuilt smtp mail package and the Message mode.

Earlier, when using the web interface I could set a font while composing the mail. Now, through emacs, when I send an email, it is received in some default variable width font. How do I make sure the mail is sent as fixed width?

Do I have to send a Html mail for that?

Answer (score 1):

If you have not specified anything, it will be the receiver's settings that matter, and that's as it should be. If you want to read your emails in a fixed width font, you should be able to set that; let others read them as they wish.

Comment: This is not a useful answer. Marking certain text regions as fixed-width makes it possible to send code in emails, tables, etc., that would otherwise show as garbled to recipients. OP's request is hence very sensible.